# When is using "undocumented" data types for VBA API calls safe? EG Currency 4 QueryPerformanceCounter or LongLong 4 GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime

Tags: vba, types

There seems to be flexibility in data types you can use for any particular API calls from VBA but I have seen no discussion about how they work or how to choose one, so how am I to know what data types are safe to use when they seem to work for small testing samples?  64 bit system/software assumed. There are lots of examples of "use this code" but I have not seen discussion of use of alternate data types.

For instance, I have successfully used three data types…Currency, UINT64 high/low (I guess the correct term in Long_Integer?), and LongLong in the declarations for QueryPerformanceFrequency …eg  in this declaration you can change LongLong to the either of the other two and use them appropriately per the data type.

Private Declare PtrSafe Function QueryPerformanceFrequency Lib "kernel32" (lpPerformanceFrequency As LongLong) As Long

And note that using Currency, you do *NOT* get the frequency…you get frequency divided by 10,000.  I have not seen any discussion on the fact that you have changed the return value to something other than that stated in the MS documentation.  If you use Currency in QueryPerformanceFrequency, and LongLong in QueryPerformanceCounter, your timer calculations will be wrong.

LongLong for FILETIME seems to go the other way too as input to API call….I created the maximum SYSTEMTIME date/time, converted this FILTETIME with LongLong (SystemTimeToFileTime), converted it back with LongLong number as the FILETIME (FileTimeToSystemTime) and got the same SYSTEMTIME date/time I started with. But if I read [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) correctly re FILETIME you shouldn't necessarily be able to do this.

I also found out by accident that if you define a UNIT64 data type with LongLong high/low values, then the returned high part is zero and the low part has all the data.  So you don’t have to convert /form union of the two High/Low to a LongLong taking into account both parts of the UNIT64, just use the value in the LowPartLL.

Eg guts of code:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime Lib "kernel32" (lpFileTime As UINT64LL) As Long

Public Type UINT64LL
    LowPartLL As LongLong
    HighPartLL As LongLong
End Type

Dim LLFTCounts as LongLong, u64LLFileTime as UINT64LL
GetSystemTimePreciseAsFile u64LLFileTime

LLFTCounts = UINT64LL.LowPartLL   ‘UINT64LL.HighPartLL is zero
```

So how do I know what data type is safe to use, assuming it can handle the max size of the original data? For instance, it would be a lot easier if I was told that it is safe to just use LongLong data type for all VBA data calls to API functions that return unsigned and signed 64 bit data, and the API would give the correct conversions.  Of course I can try a data type to see if works on a few examples I certainly do not have the skill level to do complete testing.

Answer (score 0):

When using API calls, data types must be **exactly** the correct length. VBA provides crash protection (the stack is checked after each call), so using the wrong number of bytes won't crash VBA, but responses will be wrong/random and an error condition will be set if the number of bytes is not correct.

When using computors, **values** must be exactly the correct **values**. 1=1, 2=2 etc. Using unexpected data types may make it more difficult for you to set and understand values.

Apart from those two conditions, you may call the bytes set and retrieved on the stack anything you like, and you may group them any way you like. Neither VBA or the API care.

This is different from COM objects. When you use a COM library object, the types are identified and named, and you must use the same type identifiers.

Neither VBA or the API provide a method of determining variable types. That is a limitation of the 'native' API, and is why object systems like COM exist.

---

LongLong and Currency are both 64 bit types. The *value* of LongLong and Currency are represented differently: this is an example of the kind of difference using a different data representation can cause.

Using two UINT64 variables (128 bits), where 64 bits are required is unsafe. If you transfer the declaration to Open Office, Open Office will just crash. VBA corrects the stack pointer when you make an error like that, rather than crashing. You may get the correct return value in some of the bytes, depending on exactly what the mistake you made is, or you may not. It's a computer, so it's predictable, but it's not defined behavior, so it's not safe.

'Safe' is a special word for computer programmers. It doesn't mean 'on my computer this example always works'. Your example of an unsafe call gave you the correct answer and a zero and didn't crash VBA, because of the stack alignment and VBA stack protection.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, David.  If I understand your answer correctly, then wouldn't the UINT64LL data type I created cause problems since I think it is 2X64 bits long, and the API call uses 64 bit length of data (they are not exactly the same lenght)?  And re Currency, why would it actually change the answer by dividing by 10,000 compared to integer type data types? Is it because Currency is limited to 4 decimal places, does it just take the 64 bit integer and "sticks" a decimal point in?  And does your answer say yes, I can go ahead and use LongLong for any API returning 64 bit data?

Comment: Thanks for  taking the time to provide the additional info, I understand the process better now.  I am  still too new to this site to be allowed to vote up your original response.